# Is there a way to override the lock pattern screen?

Tags: android

I want to provide my own version of password mechanism. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no APIs for you to replace the lock pattern screen, so you cannot change it from an SDK application. If you are making your own firmware, though, you can change it, though I do not know exactly how.