# Android Dialer Broadcast Receiver 

Tags: android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Service Listener for the wakelock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840869/android-service-listener-for-the-wakelock-screen)

Is there a way to write a broadcast receiver for the android phone dialer?