# How to know wether the phone is locked in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Service Listener for the wakelock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840869/android-service-listener-for-the-wakelock-screen)

I want to know how to findout the status of the phone whether its locked or not. using the source code. any suggestions on this please? any specific android permissions?